# Regarding the pause-resume data loss in MSVC std::experimental::generator

Tags: c++, generator, std-ranges, c++-coroutine, c++23

Since the `std::generator` is making it into CPP23, I am playing around with MSVC's incomplete version.

However, I notice that it seems lose exactly one `yield` when used with `std::views::take`. Here is the example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

#include <experimental/generator>

std::experimental::generator<int> GeneratorFn(void) noexcept
{
    co_yield 1;
    co_yield 2;
    co_yield 3;
    co_yield 4;
    co_yield 5;
    co_yield 6;
    co_yield 7;
    co_yield 8;
    co_yield 9;
    co_return;
}

int main(int argc, char** args) noexcept
{
    auto Ret = GeneratorFn();
    for (auto&& i : Ret | std::views::take(2))
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    for (auto&& i : Ret | std::views::take(3))
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    for (auto&& i : Ret | std::views::take(4))
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

The output of this code would be

```
1
2
4
5
6
8
9
```

and clearly, the `3` and `7` is missing. It seems like `std::views::take` drops the last value the `generator` yields.

Is this normal and to be expected in the formal version of C++23?
(Try online: https://godbolt.org/z/v6MModvaz)

Comment: Why not report the problem to Microsoft?

Comment: @Phil1970 Because generally it's VERY likely that this is my misunderstand of the standard instead of MS's. They're THE big tech in the field.

Comment: It might be unavoidable: "`std::generator` is a move-only `view` which models `input_range` and has move-only iterators." The `end` in the first `take` eats an element

Comment: This is the expected behavior, which is basically equivalent to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1Mv1Y8h7).

Comment: @Caleth Can I "bypass" this "feature" somehow?

Comment: I don't know offhand what the contract on the experimental one is, but as far as the C++23 one is concerned, it is a precondition violation (and therefore undefined behavior) to call `begin` multiple times on the same `generator`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::generator` is an `input_range`, its `begin()` does not guarantee equality-preserving:

```
auto Ret = GeneratorFn();
std::cout << *Ret.begin() << "\n"; // 1
std::cout << *Ret.begin() << "\n"; // 2
```

When your first for-loop finishes, `Ret`'s iterator has already incremented to the value `3`. When you apply `views::take` to `Ret` in the second for-loop, this will call `Ret`'s `begin` again, and the iterator return by `begin` will be the next value `4`.

If you don't want to discard the value of the end iterator, you can reuse the last end iterator like this

```
auto Ret = GeneratorFn();
auto c = std::views::counted(Ret.begin(), 2);
for (auto i : c)
  std::cout << i << '\n';
for (auto i : std::views::counted(c.begin(), 3))
  std::cout << i << '\n';
for (auto i : std::views::counted(c.begin(), 4))
  std::cout << i << '\n';
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gbchv5x7)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I aware the ```begin()``` would be different on each call, hence my original intention is to take the first 2 values into the first range, the next 3 into the second range, etc. Is there any alternative way to make my design work?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 3):

Pause-resume type behaviours want to be implemented with stateful function objects. Before you had to return `std::vector`s but now you can use `std::generator` instead

```
template<typename Gen>
auto TakeAdaptor(Gen&& gen)
{
    return [gen = std::move(gen)](int count) mutable 
        -> std::experimental::generator<int>
    {
        auto i = 0;
        if (not (i++ < count))
            co_return;
        for (auto e : gen)
        {
            co_yield e;
            if (not (i++ < count))
                break;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char** args) noexcept
{
    auto take = TakeAdaptor(GeneratorFn());
    for (auto i : take(2))
      std::cout << i << '\n';
    for (auto i : take(3))
      std::cout << i << '\n';
    for (auto i : take(4))
      std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x4957vr8z

Comment: This alternative solution looks cool! Could you explain a bit about what the ```std::move```is doing in the lambda capture? Much appreciated!

Comment: @Hydrogen `std::generator` i.e. the result of  `GeneratorFn()` is move only (deleted copy constructor) so we must move it into the lambda rather than copy it

Comment: @Hydrogen also note that you could also leave the `std::generator` on the stack and accept it by reference to a stateless adaptor function https://godbolt.org/z/cnP9d5oha

Comment: Also T.C. points you it's undefined behaviour to call begin multiple times on the generator, so technically I should replace the range-for loops with loops over raw iterators. But in reality things get done by programming off observed behaviour

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and reminder! I would try it by myself to do the replacement. And I actually kinda agree with you that "to a specific compiler everything is de facto well-defined".

Comment: *"to a specific compiler everything is de facto well-defined"*. I wouldn't say that. Rather that programming is empirical, if it passes the compile and run test, then its observed behaviour is correct. It's impractical to precede any other way. But compiler and library writers have a different measure of correctness, and well-defined (by the standard) is the vocabulary of their correctness

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could your share your opinion yet again if I change my wording to *"to a specific compiler version and a specific STL impl. version, everything is de facto well-defined."* ? I feel this wording patches all your bug reports. XD

Comment: `well-defined` already means well defined according to the standard. It's like using literally to mean figuratively. *"The observed behaviour is correct"* is a better thing to say. You probably don't yet appreciate the process of standardization in computer science

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the wording. Yes I am not a computer scientist but a chemist, thus the word "undefined behavior" just making no sense to me according to my background knowledge. I've watched several videos explaining this terminology but it still confusing me at this point 

Comment: @Hydrogen https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/153472/152730